# WinRT/WPF - Displaying recursive data without TreeView or HeirarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: data-structures, recursion, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

So in Windows 8 Metro (using C#/WinRT), I have a data structure as follows:

```
public class Comment
{
    public string body;
    public List<Comment> replies;
}
```

and would like to show it on a page, but previous methods are now unavailable in WinRT (TreeView and HeirarchicalDataTemplate). Is there anyway to do so now, in Windows 8? Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Other than implementing the TreeView control or looking for one already implemented - you could have a Frame with a ListView that has its ItemsSource bound to a list of Comments. You would wire up the ListView in such a way that tapping a comment would navigate to another Page in the Frame with a ListView and a list of replies bound to it. A back button would navigate back in the Frame to get you back to the Page for parent comment.

EDIT*

WinRT XAML Toolkit has a `TreeView` control now. Check it out: http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b0ee76bd6492#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/TreeView/TreeView.cs

Take care though - this is just a rough port from Silverlight Toolkit and might not work so well. Also if you are planning on releasing it as part of a Windows Store application - you would need to heavily restyle it unless your app is desktop-only since it is not very touch-friendly.

Comment: O_O Thanks... seems a bit hackish though :( Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: That's what the platform's file pickers do when you navigate the tree...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.aspx#Y0

I agree it's less than ideal in desktop environment and I can assure you I am already swimming against the current and pondering implementation of a TreeView in the WinRT XAML Toolkit... :)

Comment: The `TreeView` port from Silverlight Toolkit is there now.